# discord.py get all permissions a bot has

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am developing a Bot using discord.py and I want to get all permissions the Bot has in a specific Guild. I already have the Guild Object but I don't know how to get the Permissions the Bot has. I already looked through the documentation but couln't find anything in that direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Member object, like `guild.me` (a Member object similar to Bot.user, essentially a Member object representing your bot), you can get the permissions that member has from the `guild_permissions` attribute.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the Permissions Value to the Names of the Permissions?

Comment: @Moondancer iirc guild_permissions is a list of lists, like `[["manage_guild", True], [manage_messages, True]]`. The first element in each list is the permission name, the second is a boolean that denotes whether the user has the permission or not.

Comment: How can I access that list? I tried `guild_permissions[0]` but that didn't work

Comment: I think you would access the name of the first permission in the list with `guild_permissions[0][0]`

Comment: `perms = me.guild_permissions[0][0]`
`TypeError: 'Permissions' object is not subscriptable`
This is why I asked, I can't really access it

Comment: ok I found it. It is just `guild_permission.administrator` and so on for every Permission